# gnuplot - error bars and fitting for calculations from raw data

Tags: gnuplot, gaussian, propagation

What does gnuplot do if I have a data.txt file like this:

```
#x  y  dx  dy
 1  2  0.2 0.1 
 3  5  0.1 0.3
```

Where the dx and dy are the errors directly related to x and y (x +- dx, y +- dy). And I do this:

```
plot data.txt using (1/$1):($2*5):3:4 with xyerrorbars
```

Will gnuplot do this for x and y

```
(1/x) +- dx
5y +- dy
```

or that

```
1/(x +- dx)
5(y +- dy)
```

or that

```
1/x +- 1/dx
```

or that, the Gaussian error propagation, which would be the right one, gotten from the sqrt(sum(derivative times the error)^2)

```
1/x -+ dx/x^2
```

And how to fit in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnuplot will certainly do the first option  `(1/x) +- dx`.  As for the fitting, you'll have to be a little more specific ...

Comment: Thanks. The fitting question is then obsolete, anyways. Because gnuplot can do weighted least square fits, I was wondering how the errors are treated when using calculations in the plot/fit command. But if it's doing nothing at all in plotting, then it certainly won't to anything in fitting.